# How to import upsell products from products programmatically in magento1?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    //$c = 0;
    require_once '/app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();
    Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
    {
        $name = $filesop[0];
        //echo "sssssssssssssss:".$name;
        //$productId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku('sku');
        $catalog = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $product = $catalog->loadByAttribute('sku', $name);
        //$productId1 = $name;
        try {
            //$upSellProducts = $product->getUpSellProducts();
            if($product){
            //foreach ($upSellProducts as $upSellProduct) {
              //  $upSellProductsArranged[$upSellProduct->getId()] = array('position' => $$upSellProduct->getPosition());
            //}
            $upsellLinks = array();

            $upsellLinks[$product] = array('position'=>'') ;
            //$upsellLinks[$productId2] = array('position'=>'') ;
            $product->setUpSellLinkData($upsellLinks);
            $product->save();
            //$product->setUpSellLinkData($upSellProductsArranged);
            //$product->save();

    }
else
 {
     echo $name." doesn't exist<br />";
 }

} catch (Exception $e) {
      echo "Product with ID: " . $product->getId() . "cannot be created<br />";
     }

}
echo "upsell products created completed";
}
?>
<html>
<head>  
<title>import</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

import

Comment: Hi, I checked this two links but here no code.Can you please help me?

Comment: Yaa, I want to import CSV file from skus and after add upsell products in Magento products through programmatically.Can you please help me?

Comment: This is my code but it is not working.Please check my below code.

Comment: I want to add dynamically upsell products in admin

Comment: I have a problem with products adding upsell products in admin.In every product add upsell products it takes so much time.In 2000 products are there in my admin.So, I want to use SKU and import upsell products in admin through code.Can you please help me?

Comment: In CSV file I have taken product SKUs and after import CSV file through the code in my products adding upsell products.This is my requirement

Comment: <?php 
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
//$c = 0;
require_once '/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
{
$name = $filesop[0];
echo "sssssssssssssss:".$name;
//$productId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku('sku');
$catalog = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product = $catalog->loadByAttribute('sku', $name);

Comment: try {
 $upSellProducts = $product->getUpSellProducts();
//if($product){
 foreach ($upSellProducts as $upSellProduct) {
    $upSellProductsArranged[$upSellProduct->getId()] = array('position' => $$upSellProduct->getPosition());
}
//$upsellLinks = array();

$upsellLinks[$product] = array('position'=>'') ;
//$upsellLinks[$productId2] = array('position'=>'') ;

//$product->setUpSellLinkData($upsellLinks);

//$product->save();
$product->setUpSellLinkData($upSellProductsArranged);
$product->save();

//else
   //{
   // echo $name." doesn't exist<br />";
   //}

Comment: } catch (Exception $e) {
          echo "Product with ID: " . $product->getId() . "cannot be created<br />";
     }
 
}
echo "upsell products created completed";
}
?>

Comment: <html>
<head> 
<title>import</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: This is my code I have to implement but it is not working. I saved the file in Magento root folder.Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi, I am adding my code to question.Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi Please review this http://inchoo.net/magento/programmatically-create-upsell-crosssell-related-products-magento/